# How to convert map, tree map, entry set using Hashtable

Tags: dictionary, java-me, hashtable, treemap

I am totally unaware with JavaME.
Please tell me how to convert this piece of code using Hashtable
as there is no map, tree map and entry set concept in java ME.

```
Map<String, String> m = new TreeMap<String, String>(); // need to convert this line

        for (int i = 0; i < SignatureKey.size(); i++)
        {
            m.put(SignatureKey.elementAt(i),SignatureValue.elementAt(i));
        }           


    //STEP 5 Formation of parameter string
    StringBuffer Parameter = new StringBuffer();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : m.entrySet())// need to conver this line

    {
        Parameter.append(entry.getKey());
        if(entry.getValue()!=null)
        {
            Parameter.append("=");
            Parameter.append(entry.getValue());             
        }
        Parameter.append("&");      
    }
```

Thanks in Advance,
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a `SortedMap` and `Hashtable` is not, you will loose the automatic sorting, but from the code snippet this might not be a problem. Below is the Java ME version.

```
    Hashtable m = new Hashtable();

    for (int i = 0; i < SignatureKey.size(); i++) {
        m.put(SignatureKey.elementAt(i), SignatureValue.elementAt(i));
    }

    // STEP 5 Formation of parameter string
    StringBuffer Parameter = new StringBuffer();
    Enumeration keys = m.keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
        String value = (String) m.get(key);

        Parameter.append(key);
        if (value != null) {
            Parameter.append("=");
            Parameter.append(value);
        }
        Parameter.append("&");
    }
```